# Sizing for Store with 36k Products and 220 Attributes

Tags: magento2, server-setup

how should I dimension my server for a shop with 36,000 products (7k configurables)? The products have up to 220 attributes, of which about 60 are displayed on the PDP. 30 attributes are searchable.

We have a maximum of 30 users on the site at the same time.

I am currently struggling with performance problems on a CCX32 cloud server at Hetzner (8 core, 32GB RAM).
It runs Varnish, ElasticSearch, database, MySql, Redis and Magento/PHP).
The server is actually working at full capacity. (CPU Load 6 +-2; Memory always more then 2.5gb free and 13gb buffer cache)
But is that really normal? I have already tried to switch to MariaDb for the query cache, but then the indexing processes no longer ran.

I am slowly getting desperate.
How would you size the server for such a shop?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide performance improving suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to consider cloud-based solutions, such as [magento-cloud](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-cloud-service/user-guide/overview.html) ...

They can provide multiple (3) nodes to serve client traffic and database

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you haven't done so already - put Cloudflare in front of magento to offload static content assets, so bots and users not buying will have a quick page load (they also have a quite good application firewall). I dont work for them, but it's always defacto recommendation for security companies to advice you have that in front of your site.

Regarding memory usage: It's standard for Linux to allocate left over ram partly for buffers. These will be freed if the OS needs it again.

You could scale out to multiple servers, but have you actually tried to see if the flat catalog option improves things?

This was used heavily in M1, but is only recommended if you have a huge amount of products on M2.

I run several magento sites on AX61-NVMe servers with 128gb ram / 30k products on hetzner and they aren't struggling, so post more info and I can try to help.